# ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile being passed as a string during integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minitest

I have an Album model and a child Picture model, whereby a file upload is handled by carrierwave.

The app runs as intended, however fails when I try to write an integration test for the upload.

From the development log, working parameters for this appear as follows:

`Parameters: ..., "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8a42be2c78>...`

During the integration test, im getting parameters as follows:

`Parameters: ..., "images"=>["#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004706fd0>"...`

As you can see, in the test scenario, `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` is being passed through as a string (confirmed with byebug), which is causing the test to fail.

How do I get the test to pass this as the object?

**Integration Test**

```
require 'test_helper'
class AlbumsCreationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user  = users(:archer)
    @file ||= File.open(File.expand_path(Rails.root + 'test/fixtures/cat1.jpg', __FILE__))
    @testfile  ||= uploaded_file_object(PicturesUploader, :image, @file)
  end

  test "should create new album with valid info" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_difference 'Album.count', 1 do #This assertion fails
      post user_albums_path(@user), album: { title:       'test',
                                             description: 'test',
      }, images: [@testfile]
    end
    assert_redirected_to @user
  end
end
```

from test_helper.rb

```
# Upload File (Carrierwave) Ref: http://nicholshayes.co.uk/blog/?p=405
def uploaded_file_object(klass, attribute, file, content_type = 'image/jpeg')

filename = File.basename(file.path)
klass_label = klass.to_s.underscore

ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
  tempfile: file,
  filename: filename,
  head: %Q{Content-Disposition: form-data; name="#{klass_label}[#{attribute}]"; filename="#{filename}"},
  type: content_type
)
end
```

**Models**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true

  validates_presence_of :pictures
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  mount_uploader :image, PicturesUploader

  validates_integrity_of  :image
  validates_processing_of :image
  validates :image, presence: true,
                    file_size: { less_than: 10.megabytes }
end
```

**Controller**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)
    if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |file|
          debugger #file.class is String in integration test
          @album.pictures.build(image: file)
        }
    end
    if @album.save
      # end
      flash[:success] = "Album Created!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:user_id, :title, :description, :price, 
        pictures_attributes: [:id, :image, :image_cache, :_destroy])   
    end

    def valid_user
      @user = User.friendly.find(params[:user_id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

It appears that the `uploaded_file_object` method doesn't work at the integration test level.

I went back to using `fixture_file_upload` and everything works as intended.